# Expo/React Native Gif display issues

Tags: react-native, expo, gif

I have been trying to trouble this issue for days now. I am using `React Native (0.72)` and I've tried `Expo Image`, `Image Background`, etc... but I can't get the gif to not show the "frames" or make it smooth. The gif plays fine if I have it on a desktop.

```js
 <Image source={require('../assets/fly.gif')}
    style={styles.Gif} 
    contentFit="cover"
    transition={1000}/
 >
```

[image]

Comment: Provide the gif as well as a minimal re-producible repo. How can we debug this without seeing the actual gif and code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Expo SDK 40 or higher, you might need to use `asset` from `react-native-fast-image` for optimal GIF performance.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const gifUri = require('./path/to/your/gif.gif');

  return (
    <View>
      {/* Use FastImage for displaying the GIF */}
      <FastImage
        source={gifUri}
        style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
        resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: Give us the minimalist repo to work with.